# ASP.NET PasswordRecovery - New Password Doesn't Work

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, password-recovery

I have a new asp.net 4.0 website. I've added the password recovery control. I goto my forgot password page, enter my email address and I receive an email with the new password. Problem is, the new password doesn't work! I goto the login page, enter my email address and the new password I have tried a copy and paste and also very carefully typing the password manually being careful with the type case. I just get the message "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again". There's nothing in the event log.

Any ideas?

I have pasted the page code below:

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server" OnSendingMail="PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail"
    CssClass="mediumText">
    <MailDefinition From="noreply@blank.com" BodyFileName="~/EmailTemplates/PasswordRecovery.txt" />
    <UserNameTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                <h1>
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                Enter your email address to receive your password.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Email Address:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                    ErrorMessage="Email address is required." ToolTip="Email address is required."
                                    ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color: Red;">
                                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1"
                                    OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </UserNameTemplate>
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

Comment: Go to ASP.Net configuration tool and check whether there is a tickbox with a checkmark beside with your newly created account  or not if not check it and try to login

Comment: How do I get to the ASP .Net configuration tool? I'm running VS2010 on Win7 ultimate.

Comment: Go to menu Website>Asp.Net configuartion (or) In the solution explorer menu on right hand side you will have menu in that last option a globe with a hammer sign.

Comment: I have no website item on the VS menu. I think this may be because I'm running VS2010 rather than VS2008. Also, I'm not using a website project, I'm using a Web Application. I don't think it possible to get at the ASP.Net configuration page with my setup, so I've decided to use this one: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no website item on the VS menu. I think this may be because I'm running VS2010 rather than VS2008. Also, I'm not using a website project, I'm using a Web Application. I don't think it possible to get at the ASP.Net configuration page with my setup, so I've decided to use this one: 4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx